# JDBC Example for java

Tags: java, sql

I have downloaded JDK 6 and also I have sqljdb4.jar and I have database.properties file that content the following data

```
database.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
database.url=jdbc:sqlserver://.;databaseName=UserInfo;integratedSecurity=true; 
database.username=sa
database.password=admin
```

B.N : I'm installing the server on my machine and the server name = . , also I'm using Windows Authontication

My problem now is when I try to create connection I have the following error

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
>   The TCP/IP connection to the host
>   localhost, port 1433 has failed.
>   Error: Connection refused: connect.
>   Please verify the connection
>   properties and check that a SQL Server
>   instance is running on the host and
>   accepting TCP/IP connections at the
>   port, and that no firewall is blocking
>   TCP connections to the port.  at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:130)

I don't know what is the exact problem here

If any one can help I will be appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Make sure you have TCP/IP Enabled in the the SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols

Comment: yes I have enables it and also it works on port 1433 , but I'm also having the same Exception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's caused by many probabilities like
1- IP is worong
2-  Port is wrong
3- There is firewall prevent machine to go out and connect to another IP
4- SQL server down .

try to use

```
    public class JdbcSQLServerDriverUrlExample
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Connection connection = null;
    try
    {
      // the sql server driver string
      Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

      // the sql server url
      String url = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://HOST:1433;DatabaseName=DATABASE";

      // get the sql server database connection
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"THE_USER", "THE_PASSWORD");

      // now do whatever you want to do with the connection
      // ...

    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(2);
    }
  }
}
```

What i need to explain is there is very good technology called " Persistence " is better than JDBC and is more than brilliant and easy to use .

Comment: Could you provide link or a full name for the "Persistence" technology you mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your SQL server is either

- not installed,
- not running or
- not accepting TCP/IP connections.

Particularly the last one is nasty, as I remember that some versions of SQL Server have not configured the TCP/IP connector to run by default.

Answer (score 1):

Well first and foremost we need to see your code.  Second looking at the error message the database is A)not running
B) on a different port
or C) the code is incorrect.