# SQL Server with Java EE Walkthrough

Tags: java, sql-server, jakarta-ee

I have looked all over the net for a tutorial on writing a Java EE web app with sql server but I cant find it.  Can anyone point me in the right direction.  I will be calling stored procedures I have written also.

Comment: Go through [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html) and understand

Comment: That is mysql though, is there a big difference though?

Comment: Yes that is a mysql.The java code remain same except for some line like ` Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      // setup the connection with the DB.
      connect = DriverManager
          .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback?"
              + "user=sqluser&password=sqluserpw");`

Comment: Also go throgh [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885599/jdbc-example-for-java) but here no explanation is given